# serialPort not reading value properly

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I been trying to read the temperature/humidity monitoring device through serialport(Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port) but the values i'm getting is not what i'm expecting. May be I'm going somewhere wrong.

Here what I have tried so far.

Port Settings:

```
PortName:Com1
BaudRate: 38400
DataBits: 8
DiscardNull:False
DtsEnable:False
GenerateMember: True
Handshake: None
Parity: None
ParityReplace:63
ReadBuffersize:4096
ReadTimeout: -1
ReceivedBytesThreshold:1
RtsEnable: False
StopBits:One
WriteBufferSize: 2048
WriteTimeout:-1
```

```
private void SerialPortTH_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (rtxMsg.InvokeRequired)
        {
            rtxMsg.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                //this is my work
                int bufferToRead = SerialPortTH.BytesToRead;
                buffer = new byte[bufferToRead];
                SerialPortTH.Read(buffer, 0, bufferToRead);
                rtxMsg.Text += BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
                rtxMsg.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("incomingData.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(rtxMsg.Text);
            }
        }));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (lblException.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lblException.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                lblException.Text += ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
01
44-0B-01-65-01-D6-14-59-F9-70
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-E4-BF-F2
00-30-E4-E4-3F-40
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-E4-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-B9
01
44-0B-01-65-01-D6-14-5A-F9-25
01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-E4-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-B9
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-E4-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F
40
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-E4-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-B9
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-5B-F9-D6
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38
BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4
3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3
38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01-44-0B
01-64-01-D6-14-5C-F9-B8
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-5D-F9-7C
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-5E-F9-29
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00
30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3
00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-5F-F9-ED
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-60-F9-D8
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-61-F9-1C
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
44-0A-01-64-01-D6-14-62-F9-0A-01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-19
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-E0
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-19
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-63-F9-8D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F
08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
44-0B-01-64-01-D6-14-64-F9-E3
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3
00-30-E4-E4-3F-08
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4
3F-F1
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-E4
E4-3F-08
01
44-0A-01-64-01-D6-14-65-F9-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-19
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-BE-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-E0
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-BE-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-19-01-44-0A-01-63-01-D6-14-66-F9-B4
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-33
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-CA
01
44-0A-01-63-01-D6-14-67-F9-70
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3
00-30-BE-E4-3F-33
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-CA
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-33
01
44-0B-01-63-01-D6-14-68-F9-2B
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-22
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-DB
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-22
01
44-0A-01-63-01-D6-14-69-F9-AC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F
33
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-CA
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-33-01-44-0B-01-63-01-D6-14-6A-F9-BA
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-22
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-DB
01
44-0B-01-63-01-D6-14-6B-F9-7E
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-22
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-DB
01
44-0A-01-63-01-D6-14-6C-F9-53
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-33
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-CA
01
44-0B-01-63-01-D6-14-6D-F9-D4
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-B6-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-22
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-B6-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-DB
01
44-0B-01-62-01-D6-14-6E-F9-B6-01-47-F2
00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-AD
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-54
01
44-0B-01-62-01-D6-14-6F-F9-72
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-AD
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-54
01
44-0A-01-62-01-D6-14-6F-F9-31
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-BC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-45
01
44-0B-01-62-01-D6-14-70-F9-86
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-E4-E4-3F-AD
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-E4-E4-3F-54
01
44-0A-01-62-01-D6-14-71-F9-01-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA
F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-45
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-BC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-45
01
44-0A-01-62-01-D6-14-72-F9-54
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-BC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-45
01
44-0A-01-62-01-D6-14-73-F9-90
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-BC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-45
01-44-0A
01-62-01-D6-14-74-F9-FE
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-66-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-BC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-66-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-45
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-75-F9-63
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-6F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-76-F9-36
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-6F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-77-F9-F2
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-6F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96-01-44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-78-F9-EA-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-6F-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96-01-44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-79-F9-2E
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-6F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-7A-F9-7B
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-E4-3F-6F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-7B-F9-BF
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-E4-3F-96
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
44-0B-01-61-01-D6-14-80-F9-46
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-E4-FE-3F-8C
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-E4-FE-3F-75
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-81-F9-C1
01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-82-F9-94
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-83-F9-50
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-84-F9-3E
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-85-F9-FA-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F
9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-60-01-D6-14-86-F9-98
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-DA-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-1F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-DA-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-E6
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-DA-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-1F
01
44-0A-01-60-01-D6-14-87-F9-5C
01-47
F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-DA-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-1F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-DA-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-E6
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-DA-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-1F
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-88-F9-73
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-89-F9-B7-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-8A-F9-E2
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-8B-F9-26
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-8C-F9-48
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D-01-44-0A-01-61-01-D6
14-8D-F9-8C
01-47
F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-8E-F9-D9
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-60-01-D6-14-8F-F9-2A
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-DA-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-1F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-DA-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-E6
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-90-F9-E9
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-91-F9-2D-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-92-F9-78
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-93-F9-BC
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-94-F9-D2
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-95-F9-16
01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-96-F9-43
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-97-F9-87
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-98-F9-9F
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64-01-44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-99-F9-5B-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-9A-F9-0E
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D-01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64-01-44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-9B-F9-CA
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-9C-F9-A4
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
44-0A-01-61-01-D6-14-9D-F9-60
01-47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F3-38-F2-BF-F3-00-30-BE-FE-3F-64
01
47-F2-00-FC-00-B7-DA-F2-38-F2-BF-F2-00-30-BE-FE-3F-9D
```

Comment: Make sure that the speed of the both serial ports is identically

Comment: Please see my edit question, I have added the setting of my serialport.

Comment: There is no two serialport here.. only one port just reading the device.

Comment: The device has a serial port too, that has a specific speed. Can you post the exact name of the _temperature/humidity monitoring device _?

Comment: Whatever you are getting from the device, it is not ASCII.  You can tell from the many ? question marks, that's a byte that could not be converted.  Maybe the baudrate is wrong, 38400 is a pretty unusual choice.  Maybe the device sends binary data instead of text.  You'll have to RTFM or use the telephone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I calculate the values. 
first remove the dashes from the incoming data and slow down the reading by 150 milliseconds. 
Thread.sleep(150).

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
int buffToRead = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[buffToRead];
serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffToRead);
string rStream = BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", "");
```

this will give you:

```
0144F100B501E114AD44A101476600FC00F3DA6738E4676100C060FE3F37
```

I alway check whether the value is greater than 50 and starts with 0144.
this gives me accurate result. 
after this 0144 the first Hex value

```
F1 = Hex to Dec 241/10 = 24.10
```

Temperature is 24.10 degree celcius and second value 00B5 where I have converted 00 to 1 = 1B5

```
1B5 = Hex To Dec = 437/10 = 43.7 Humidity.
```

There are also other stuff you need to do such as CRC checksum to make sure data is correct all the time.